# If a theme enqueues a style in it's functions.php, how can you de-register it in the child theme to keep it when updating the theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

We're using OceanWP but have problems with Simple-Line-Icons and other fonts loaded.

The fonts are loaded in OceanWPs Functions PHP. Example:

```
// Register simple line icons style
        wp_enqueue_style( 'simple-line-icons', $dir .'third/simple-line-icons.min.css', false, '2.4.0' );
```

How can we de-enqueue/de-register them in our child theme so we keep it save from theme updates? Otherwise we'd have to bracket out the line on each update.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: I think you are looking for the [wp_deregister_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_deregister_style/) hook

Comment: This worked out fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it myself by adding custom function to deregister all unnessecary scripts in a snippet

```
/**
 * Disable the Simple Line Icon scripts
 */
function my_enqueue_scripts() {

    // Unregister JS files
    wp_deregister_script( 'simple-line-icons' );

    // Unregister CSS file
    wp_deregister_style( 'simple-line-icons' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts', 99 );
```

This works for now, not sure though if this is the best route to take :-)